# Sequelize: How to compute where clause programatically

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize version 4.37.6 with sqlite3.

I am building a query interface which gives me queries which I am then parsing to give sequelize compatible `where` clause.

As a simple example I have this where clause:

```
{ country: { [Op.eq]: 'Germany' } }
```

(`Op.eq` is just an example, but I need others, so just simply `{ country: 'Germany'}` is not an option).
Syntactically this is correct, but the problem is that my parser returns this as a string, while sequelize expects an object. If I copy and paste my `where` strings directly into the query program the queries all work fine. They look identical to the string but they are obviously pasted as an object into the editor (VS Code).
`JSON.parse()` does not work because of the `[Op.eq]` symbol. I have tried to use `$eq` but I did not manage to get that to work either (and it is not the recommended way anymore).

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
function parseTerm (term) {
  const attributeList = ['country', 'province', 'city', 'location', 'label', 'rating', 'category', 'genre']
  const operatorList = ['==', '>=', '<=', '!=', 'like', 'in']
  var attribute = term.split(' ')[0].substr(1)
  var operator = term.split(' ')[1]
  var value = ''
  if (attributeList.includes(attribute) && operatorList.includes(operator)) {
    value = term.substr(attribute.length + operator.length + 3).slice(0, -1)
    var sequelizeOpr = [Op.eq]
    console.log(sequelizeOpr)
    if (operator === '==') {
      sequelizeOpr = '[Op.eq]'
    }

    let returnString = `${attribute}: { ${sequelizeOpr}: '${value}' }`
```

I know I have to somehow generate an Object, but I do not know how to do this while dynamically substituting values.....
Any suggestions ??

JD

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to query?

Comment: Why dont you return an object with de given structure?

Comment: Example of what I want to query: a Table Image with attributes shown above in the attribute list. So what I want to achieve with the example query is "select * from image where country = 'Germany'". This is of course only a very basic example. All possible combinations of the attributes and operators should be handled.